# Using Python in Mathematica : RegisterExternalEvaluator doesn't work

Tags: external-calls, python

I followed this tutorial https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ConfigurePythonForExternalEvaluate.html, installed zmq, restarted mathematica and put this code:

```
RegisterExternalEvaluator["Python", "C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\python"]
```

(it is the good path to the python executable, I also tried without the .exe)

However mathematica returns me

> RegisterExternalEvaluator::location: The executable C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python isn't usable for ExternalEvaluate.

The command FindExternalEvaluators["Python"] only returns me the same error.

How to fix it ?

Comment: The path should be the full absolute path name to the executable itself (not a directory containing it). The .exe should not be omitted.

Comment: @Szabolcs python.exe is exactly this file. I added the .exe but it doesnt work

Comment: @StarBucK do you have a username you use on your machine? Maybe this is what is missing from the file path.

Comment: This seems to also not work in iOS with the .app extension 

There is a Wolfram support answer about this, but I don't think it fully addresses the issues discussed: https://support.wolfram.com/42342